# Changing class attributes outside class

Tags: c#, encapsulation

I have a public class

```
 public class Interview
{
    public int InterviewId;
    public string ApplicantName;
    ...
    public List<AnsweredQuestions> AnsweredQuestions;
    public Questionnaire questionnaire;

}
```

and use it in a main program like this:

```
 Interview interview = new Interview();
 interview.InterviewId = 1;
```

and a Questionnaire class

```
public class Questionnaire
{
    public int questionnaireId;
    public string outputFile;
    ...
}
```

How can I prevent modifying the attribute int the main program:

```
interview.questionnaire.outputFile
```

I found I was able to use the DocumentManager class in the main program like this:

```
interview = documentManager.GetInterviewSession();
interview.questionnaire = documentManager.GetQuestionnaireManagement();
interview.AnsweredQuestions = documentManager.GetInterviewAnsweredQuestions();
```

by using this

```
public class DocumentManager
{
    private readonly Interview _interview;
```

...

```
public DocumentManager(Interview interview)
    {
        _interview = interview;

    }
```

I'm sure I should be encapsulating, but I'm not sure how. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I entirely get the question, but this is the usual method for read-only encapsulation:

```
public class Questionnaire
{
    public string OutputFile { get; private set; }
}
```

This creates a property named `OutputFile` that can be read publically, but only written by the `Questionnaire` class.

Alternatively, you may want to use `protected set;` if you want classes deriving from Questionnaire to be able to set `OutputFile`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try protected set, even if there arent any derived classes yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you need certain properties to be [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) then you  can supply those properties in the constructor of the class.

Also instead of using fields, you can use properties that allow you to dictate whether the property getter and setter are private/public/internal/protected.

In your sample, you could have InterviewId as a property with a public get accessor and a private only set accessor. This means that only the class itself can set the interviewId. If the only way to set the interviewId is at the constructor of the class, then there is no way for the consuming code to change it (other than by using reflection of course)

```
public class Questionnaire
{

    public Questionnaire(int questionnaireId, string outputFile)
    {
         QuestionnaireId = questionnaireId;
         OutputFile = outputFile
    } 

    public int QuestionnaireId {get; private set;} 
    public string OutputFile { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```